# Is it possible to create a button "connect to wallet"?

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, truffle-compile

I'm learning web3 and blockchain in general. I'd like to create a button that says "connect to wallet " in order to connect with metamask wallet, but I do not know if

1- I need to connect first with web3 and generate de smart contract deployed, and then when the users clicks the connect to wallet i just need to pull the accounts

2- That button will trigger everything (web3 initialization, smartcontract deployed in the provider with truffle-contract, and then get the accounts)

how should be the behavior?